# Right approach for communication with file server from web app

Tags: java, fileserver

We have a number of spring boot Rest based User applications(each hosted on different machine) with angular as the front end for UI. Some of these applications need to store documents like images, docs and excel and other user files. Initially we planned to store the files in DB but on analysis of requirements we concluded it would be better to keep them in a separate machine.

> I am looking for somewhat right approach to do so though I do realize
>   it is a broad area.
>
> 1. On file server create a restful spring boot app for multipart
>      requests  and let the angular app's directly call the file server
>      that saves the files on disk.  The file server may need a db for
>      storing the metadata
> 2. The angular UI app call the user applications (multipart
>      requests)  which will do a rest template call to the file server
>      springboot app.
> 3. The angular UI app call the user applications (multipart request)
>      and let there be a  different mode of file transfer like sftp
>      between application servers and flie server.
> 4. Let there be a shared drive on file server that each node can
>      write to.

All these apps will be hosted on same network.

Comment: What is the exact question ?

Comment: Have a look at Amazone S3.

Comment: I didnt mention S3 (google cloud etc) since we are not looking for a cloud based solution

Comment: Then deploy a compatible alternative such as Minio, Swift, Ceph, or NFS

Comment: Basically, you're looking for self hosted object storage, and there's plenty of available options

Comment: @ cricket_007 :Great! I will have a look at their feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can go about creating your own full fledged file storage web server with multiple functionalities like - **upload** file, **serve** file, **list** file etc. [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) has a complete spring based example of creating such web server. You can refer to this git repo for code -

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files

`Fork` and `add` your own functionalities whatever you want. **However** there are **plenty** of working out of the box softwares to create a web servers to expose these functionalities, simply search for **http file server** and you will get a lot of these.